# Expand the range of a list equally by keeping the same number of elements

Tags: python

You have a couple of lists of variable lengths, each starting where the previous one finished:

```
list_a = list(range(0,100)) # -133 from 233
list_b = list(range(100,150)) # -183 from 233
list_c = list(range(150,200)) # -183 from 233
list_d = list(range(200,600)) # +167 from 233
```

These lists should be transformed so that their range is from their start number to +233, but keeping the same number of elements: list_a 100 elements, list_b 50 elements etc.

So in the end the lists should look like:

```
list_a = list(range(0,233))
list_b = list(range(233,466))
list_c = list(range(466,699))
list_d = list(range(699,932))
```

I can't just change the first and last members of the list, because the difference must be spread evenly between members of the list.
So `list_a` must look like this because it's last member is lower than 233:

```
[0, 1+some_value, 2+some_value, 233]
```

`list_d` has more than 233 members so we should subtract:

```
[699, 670 - some_value, 671 - some_value, 932]
```

Any idea how to calculate the some_value for all lists?

Thanks!

Comment: You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem. [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @wwii that question is more related to a student task. This one, imo, is pretty common with plots, for example I you want to reduce the indexes to a certain range.

Comment: Are you asking a maths question? - how to evenly space x numbers between two endpoints?

Comment: @wwii yes. that is a better formulation of my question. i can't find the right formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to evenly space `X` points between two endpoints you can use [numpy.linspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
np.linspace(start_point, end_point, num=X)
```